# What is the use of Mind Mapping software?

Tags: mind-mapping

I have downloaded the Xmind software which is a mind mapping
application.

Can somebody tell me what the use of, or rather what
exactly is, mind mapping software?

Comment: If you don't know what it is, you don't need it.

Comment: I need it, but i am not sure the use of it. Can you pls explain me

Comment: Mind mapping software is for mind mapping.  If you're asking "What is mind mapping?", that's outside Superuser's scope.  Voting to close.  But to answer the question, it's like a different arrangement for essentially a hierarchal bulleted list.  Pretty much outlining, you know I, A, 1, a, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_concept_mapping_and_mind_mapping_software):

> Concept mapping and Mind mapping
>   software are used to create diagrams
>   of relationships between concepts,
>   ideas or other pieces of information.
>   It has been suggested that the mind
>   mapping technique can improve
>   learning/study efficiency up to 15%
>   over conventional note taking.

See also [Mind Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_mapping):

> A mind map is a diagram used to
>   represent words, ideas, tasks, or
>   other items linked to and arranged
>   around a central key word or idea.
>   Mind maps are used to generate,
>   visualize, structure, and classify
>   ideas, and as an aid to studying and
>   organizing information, solving
>   problems, making decisions, and
>   writing.